# Rails PDF generation in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, model, prawn, wicked-pdf

I am writing and invoicing application in Ruby On Rails, which is supposed to generate a PDF from a model so called `out_invoice` to an `in_invoice` under certain conditions.

The PDF for the `out_invoice` is already separately generated on demand using `wicked_pdf` gem basically having a HTML template and sending back the PDF inside the action and downloading it.

I have successfully programmed the duplication inside the `out_invoice` model which works fine for all values of the `out_invoice`. Including an attached PDF in a separate attribute.

But instead of generating the PDF and attaching it to the `in_invoice`. It fails. Some Controller/Model MVC thing I assume!

The PDF for the `out_invoice` is currently generated separately in a controller action so I tried copying the code: I tried rendering the template inside the model which seems to work fine, but "sending" is not defined for Rails models. If I just return the `WickedPDF` without sending it I get an error: `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature`

Must be something super simple I am forgetting + I have no clue what is the reason for the error. I am not a front-end guy so don't want to use something else as the already existing HTML template for rendering. But worst case I write the template newly in another engine. Looked at Prawn but this means rewriting everything.

Can somebody help? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, maintainer of wicked_pdf here. I don't understand what you are asking and what problem you are running into. It sounds like you got it to render the template to a PDF in your model, but I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with "sending"?

Comment: Hi @Unixmonkey solved th above issue by a consultant helping me like so: in my model I call render and rendering a str as PDF using wicked: ```pdf_str = Home::OutInvoicesController.render(
          template: "home/out_invoices/pdf",
          layout: 'pdf',
          assigns:  {
            out_invoice: self,
            bank_account: company.bank_account_for_invoice
          }
        )
        pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(pdf_str)
        in_invoice.physical_copy.attach(io: StringIO.new(pdf), filename: "#{pdf_name}.pdf")```

Comment: Cool. I'm glad it worked out for you!